# qtip2 - is it possible to change tooltip position for mobile

Tags: qtip2

I want to change the position of my tooltip from:

```
position: {
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'right center'
}
```

to (only for the mobile resolutions):

```
position: {
        my: 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center'
}
```